# Designing of reliable multicast algorithm, regarding validity, can you deliver before multicasting

Tags: distributed-systems

As the title says, if an algorithm delivers $m$ before multicasting $m$, does the validity property still hold? I would argue that it doesn't matter, as the purpose of validity is to ensure that the process reaches consensus with the other processes that it multicasts to.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "the validity property"?  What is the context?  Are you reading something somewhere?  What do you mean by "delivers m before multicasting m"?  What's an "af reliable multicast algorithm"?  Is "af" a typo?

Comment: Sorry that must have been a typo. So im trying to design an application with the intentionen of implementing a reliable multicast protocol. From what i have learned in the distributed systems course i have attended this semester, there are 3 properties that needs to be fulfilled to be a reliable multicast protocol. The 3 properties are Integrity, Validity and Agreement.

These can be found in George Coulouris's Distributed Systems Concepts and Design.

The Validity property mentioned in the book says "If a correct process multicasts message m, then it will eventually deliver m.

Comment: The application i am trying to implement this into, is a file storage system that already has delivered the message m before multicasting it.

My question is, is the protocol im trying to design and implement still reliable multicast, or is it important that the message m is multicast before the delivery of the message?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't know what you mean by "delivered", and I'm not sure what kind of reliability guarantees you need, and I'm not sure what your protocol is.  Why do you think it might be important to multicast before delivery?  What are your thoughts?  You might need to explain all of that for people to be able to help you.